# There are no usable controls in this group. Drag an item onto this text to add it to the toolbox" Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

Its Not a Programming Question But about Visual studio express 2012.
Trying to create a new report in the visual studio 2012 but can not see the list of data sets, parameters etc: In general tab i am seeing this

"There are no usable controls in this group. Drag an item onto this text to add it to the toolbox"

I have searched to fixed it but not succeeded till now..

Comment: right click on your package and check whether you follow any options

Comment: Are you on design page?

Comment: yes ".rdlc design" page but its on all pages whether design, or code or dataset ".xsd" page

Answer (score 31):

I came across this same issue today and read plenty of things such as "this is VS bug...." but the solution was much simpler than that, I just needed to stop debugging (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>).

If that doesn't work, I recommend restarting the IDE.

If this doesn't work, I guess that uninstalling VS and doing a fresh installation is the answer you're looking for. It's important to note that it's recommended to restart Windows after installing VS and before launching it.

Comment: I think a restart is more than enough.  Stopping debugging worked for me.

Answer (score 29):

Right click on the Toolbox and press "Show All"

[image]

Answer (score 15):

Right click on Toolbox, Click on "choose Items.". Restart IDE. That worked for me.

Comment: For Visual Studio 2012, right click on Toolbox and select "Choose Items..". On the Choose Toolbox Items dialog, click "Reset".

Comment: In Visual Studio Community Edition 2015, I had to right click in the Toolbox and select "Choose Items", then right click and choose "Show All"

Comment: run visual studio installer => repair =>restart computer its OK

Answer (score 8):

Right click on Toolbar and select: Reset Toolbox.

MFC controls will reappear.

[image]

Comment: Still works like a charm in Visual Studio 2022  :-)

Answer (score 3):

I also had this problem, and it turned out I was trying to open the wrong toolbox: what I was actually looking for was the 'SSIS toolbox'. If none of the other options have worked, try selecting View -> Other Windows -> SSIS Toolbox. That fixed it for me.

[I found this out from [this blog by James Serra](http://www.jamesserra.com/archive/2013/01/ssis-2012-empty-toolbox/)]

In VS 2015, the SSIS Toolbox is under SSIS tab, not under View.

Comment: Yes, as shown in the link StefanOS provided, there is a tiny icon in the top right corner of the Package Design Window. If you click on that it'll bring back your SSIS Toolbox

Answer (score 2):

"There are no usable controls..." is shown when you have currently opened a file that is not designer file (e.g. "Form1.cs"). Once you open the designer file (e.g. "Form1.Designer.cs") the items should be shown again.

Comment: What kind of project do I need to choose? I don't even see any `*.CS` files with either MFC or Win32 projects :-(

Answer (score 1):

Just hover over the design and then press escape.  A control that you had selected and not dropped is holding up memory.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me, and it was because I was currently debugging.  Once I ended debugging, the usable controls appeared.